# How can I non blockingly await a REST API fetch in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I want to build a Java application that works with web sockets and REST requests.
Basically, whenever a user connects, a Web socket connection is opened for him so he can interact with the application (through a web interface). He can then request certain interactions with the System (such as undoing an Action or fetching certain information from a database or a rest api) and receive a reply once their finished (or an outside system interacts with the application, such as information being streamed piecewise or a mail is received).

A lot of these interactions look like this:

```
UponReceivingMessageFromWebsocket(String mess)
     if(mess=="get_weather"):
          String location=checkDatabaseForUserLocation()  //async; js would await here
          String wheater=fetchWeatherLocationFromApi("api.weather.com/") //async; js would await here
          user.setWeather(wheater) 
          websocket.synchronizeWeather()//async; js would await here
     if(mess="stream_text"):
          String chunk=""
          while(chunk!=null):
               chunk=fetchNextChunkFromAPI()//async; js would await here
               user.streamedText+=chunk
               websocket.synchronizeText()//async; js would await here
               if(taskCancelled)
                   break

UponReceivingMail(String Mail)
     user.mails.add(mail) 
     websocket.synchronizeMail() //async; js would await here
```

Unfortunately, from what I've seen, Java usually just whaits for all the async marked operations to complete, completely blocking the Thread in the process. This is a problem for 2 reasons:

- I still want other users to be served, while wating for a REST fetch, websocket interaciton or database operation is being completed
- I still want the user to be served mail, while wating for a REST fetch, websocket interaciton or database operation is being completed (the api I'm using is often very slow)

Now the usual remedy for this is to use a different thread for each user. But that doesn't solve the second problem and I feel like more than one thread for an application that just handles a tiny bit of buisness logic and spends most its time waiting for API requests is overkill.

In JS you have the concept of asynchronous functions, that keep all their state, block themselves from continuing until the operation is finished, but don't block the threads. They essentially use cooperative multitasking, meaning once their done with their non blocking work, they pass on the thread to some other work process (such as receiving mail or handling another user). Unfortunately using JavaScript is not an option.

Is there a way to do this in Java or solve this in some other way? Retain function state without blocking the whole thread?

Comment: Take a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ along with Java 21 Virtual Threads

Comment: You basically want to write an http server...why not use spring or tomcat?

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel The code is just to visualize the Problem. But yes its mostly web things and yes I'm using tomcat. The problem is how I can achieve asynchronous programming

Comment: @JustinKSU from what I've seen, if you join a virtual thread, its still blocks the main thread completely. You'd have to nonblockingly join (wait for)  the virtual threads. Meaning the main thread (the one calling the fetch, sql and ws fucntions which are in virtual threads) would still get blocked and the main thread would  be unable to send mails, serve other users  or do anything else while wating for any virtual thread.

Comment: there are reactive libs you can use: spring reactive, reactivex, reactor

Comment: does spring create virtual thread for every request and websocket message? Because that might be the solution